# I can vote... past my limits

Tags: support, voting

Any user can only cast 40 votes per day. This apparently skipped me for some reason. I wanted to exit the vote count of a question by "downvoting" the question. Knowing that I have reached my vote limit, the vote should be negated and the vote count should disappear. The thing is, the vote wasn't negated:

[image]
[image]

It was even recorded in my history and I reached the cap for today long ago:

[image]

The "Votes Cast" count and close vote is for verification that this is my account. Anyways, I am wondering why I can still vote even though I have reached the vote limit. And yes, the vote is still there and locked:

[image]

Proof I can't vote on other questions:

[image]

**TL;DR:** I can still vote even though I have past my vote limit. How am I doing this and when will it be fixed?

Comment: You get 10 extra question votes per day; that might be messing with things here.

Comment: Extra? But why would I get that pop-up saying I have exceeded my vote limit?

Comment: If you use 30 answer votes in a day, it'll tell you that you don't have any more. You *might* still be able to use your extra 10 on questions, though - I'm not sure.

Comment: I always thought the limit was 40. A most interesting point. Please see my edit @ArtOfCode

Comment: @ArtOfCode if you blow 30 votes on all answers, you don't get as many question-only votes.

Comment: According to your vote history, you only have 38 active votes recorded for yesterday. Remember that if you retract a vote the same day *or* a post gets deleted the same day, you get that vote back to re-cast on something else. I don't see any bug here.

Comment: @animuson The bug here is that pop-up saying that I did reach 40 votes. Even weirder is that it is blue!

Comment: The initial notice is blue because the vote you just cast caused you to hit your limit. That was your last vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @animuson, I apparently just reached 40 votes with that vote cast:

> According to your vote history, you only have 38 active votes recorded for yesterday. Remember that if you retract a vote the same day or a post gets deleted the same day, you get that vote back to re-cast on something else. I don't see any bug here.

This was a most interesting case... Well problem solved. Now I need to know why I got so confused with my vote counts...